# CPS merge sort causes a stack overflow

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

Since I had problems with stack overflows due to a non-tail recursion, I used the continuations so as to make sorting of large list feasible.

I implemeneted the sorting this way (you can see the whole code here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13481004/)

```
let merge_sort l =
    let rec merge_sort' l cont =
        match l with
        | [] -> cont []
        | [x] -> cont [x]
        | _ ->
            let (a,b) = split l
            in
                merge_sort' a
                    (fun leftRes -> merge_sort' b
 (* OVERFLOW HERE *)                (fun rightRes -> cont (merge leftRes rightRes) )
                    )
    in merge_sort' l (fun x -> x)
```

I get a stack overflow nevertheless, in the indicated line.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(@)` of OCaml's standard library is *not* tail recursive.  `merge` function in your code http://paste.ubuntu.com/13481004/ uses `(@)`, and this is the cause of the stack overflow.

`list.mli` says:

```
val append : 'a list -> 'a list -> 'a list
(** Catenate two lists.  Same function as the infix operator [@].
   Not tail-recursive (length of the first argument).  The [@]
   operator is not tail-recursive either. *)
```

but unfortunately this fact is not written in `pervasives.mli` where `(@)` is really declared:

```
val ( @ ) : 'a list -> 'a list -> 'a list
(** List concatenation. *)
```

This is not good :-(  I have filed an issue for it at OCaml dev page.

I redefined `(@)` as `fun x y -> rev_append (rev x) y` then your code runs w/o stack overflow. More elegantly, you can replace codes like `(rev a) @ l` by `rev_append a l`.

P.S. `(@)` in `pervasives.mli` will be commented as "not tail recursive" in the next release of OCaml.

Comment: the quick_sort procedure is an old function not used anywhere I have to rewrite. The problem is in merge_sort.

Comment: I do not understand. In your code, `merge_sort` uses `merge`, and `merge` uses `(@)` which is NTR.  Have you tried my  fix?

Comment: You were right, I forgot I had the appendation in merge. Thanks!